# Rails 3, Object#edit form doesn't display Nested fields_for values, Object has_many of nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, has-many

I have Recommendations that has_many Approvals.

I have a form partial from scaffolded Recommendations.

```
<%= f.fields_for :approval do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

In the new action this builds an approval: @recommendation.approvals.build

In the edit action the field is blank.  I need someone to be able to edit this if the email provided is incorrect or something.  But with a has_many association how do I edit the email address of this first approval?

thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.fields_for :approvals do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

You have to use `fields_for :approvalS`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong:

### Improper pluralization

Your `recommendation` has_many `approvals` (not `approval`). As such, your for should be:

```
<%= f.fields_for :approvals do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

### Need nested attributes

You need to tell the `Recommendation` that you are willing to accept `Approval` objects in a  `recommendation`:

```
# app/models/recommendation.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :approvals # add more options here
```

Comment: The pluralization was the issue. I had the Recommendation model stuff working fine.  Thanks so much